# How to update and delete specific value in html table without mysql

Tags: php, html

I have a form tag in which I have an input name and on click of a button, the value is displayed in table form. Now I want to update that value. How do I do it? This code does not have any database.

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="btn_submit" />

    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table border="1">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Update</th>
    <?php
    session_start();
    $na = array();
    if (isset($_GET['btn_submit'])) 
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) 
                {
                    $na = $_SESSION['name'];
                }

        $na[] = $_GET['fname'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $na;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($na); $i++) {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $na[$i]; ?></td>
                    <td><a href = "Delete.php" name="del">DELETE</a></td>
                     <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['del']))
                        {

                        }
                     ?>
                     <td><a href = "Upadte.php" name="up">UPDATE</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: you can do it by jQuery = > $('selectort').val("fgg");

Comment: without using jquery or js

Comment: if you want to set value without page refresh than you must need js.

Comment: how can i do it with passing id to another page using session